# Passing IDbSet<class> to generic method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, generics

I'm sure this is pretty basic but I have trouble constructing generic methods. I have numerous 
interfaces declared in my `DBContext` class (`IDbSet<Person>`, `IDbSet<Organizations>`, etc.). I want to pass them into a method that will process them. In this case by deleting records.
This is what I tried to do but I can't figure out how to create the method signature.

```
private static void EmptyTable<T>(ContactContext context, T records)
    {

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            records.Remove(record);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that you have 2 generic types. One is the collection type, the other is the type of the element the collection contains.

I would suggest you change your signature to

```
private static void EmptyTable<T>(ContactContext context, IDbSet<T> records)
```

That is the simplest way to do it. Otherwise you will need to do something more extravagant like

```
private static void EmptyTable<T,E>(ContactContext context, T records) 
    where T : IDbSet<E>
```

<strike>As an aside, the reason for `ICollection<T>` is that it's the simplest interface that exposes the `Remove` method, and IDbSet implements that interface I would assume.</strike>

Turns out IDbSet does not implement `ICollection`, so... you'll have to use `IDbSet`